# Unable to publish html webpage on IIS

Tags: html, publishing, iis-8

I created a simple html web page and wanted to publish on IIS 8 express. I am using Windows 8 Pro. I want to open my webpage by simply typing 'localhost' in the browser. Therefore I copied my webpage to C:\inetpub\wwwroot and as I type "localhost" the default II8 page comes.

Then I went to Content view > selected myPage.html and clicked on "Browse". I opened but I noticed the webaddress is : localhost:8080/myPage.html

I am not able to understand why it is coming with Port No and What I have to do if I want my page to be opened bydefault instead IIS8 by simply typing "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

Replace you page with IIS default page.

Comment: I could have done that, All I am trying to know if there is a way I can set Default page for my website?

Comment: Check this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320051) . Also you can do this by --> On IIS Manager--> Http view--> double click on Default and write the name of your desired startup page, Thats it